# Bootstrap table not reacting to input

Tags: javascript, jsp, bootstrap-table

I've got a problem with a bootstrap table I'm working on.

The table loads all the data as desired, but whenever I try to use some input on the table(Sort by, search, go to next page) there is no reaction. 
The footer adjusts the values, i.e. "Showing 1 to 15 of 38 rows" when I page through, but the data shown remains the same.

**Version:** *1.11.1*

**Bootstrap-table CDN:**

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US.js

**Table config:**

```
<table id="inboundTable" 
    data-toggle="table"
    data-side-pagination="server" 
    data-pagination="true"
    data-page-size="15" 
    data-page-list="[15,25,50]"
    data-sort-name="deliveryDate" 
    data-sort-order="desc"
    data-search="true" 
    data-show-refresh="true" 
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-cache="false" 
    data-filter-control="true"
    data-filter-show-clear="true" 
    data-filter-show-toggle="true"
    data-filter-show-on-default="false" 
    data-cookie="true"
    data-cookie-id-table="inboundTable" 
    data-locale="${LOCALE}">
```

**Dynamic URL in JS:**

```
$('#inboundTable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/api/production/clerk/'+currYear+'/'+weekNo});
```

**Sample Data:**

```
{  
    "total":3,
    "limit":15,
    "offset":0,
    "rows":[  
        {  
            "quantity":1,
            "manufacturingTargetDate":1528408800000,
            "clerkPhone":null,
            "glasOrderTargetDate":null
        }
    ]
}
```

If anyone needs more information, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you HTML encode your url?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what this means.

Comment: Give an example URL as a string :)

Comment: decoded:
https://www.google.com/
encoded:
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
I guess? :D

I am not doing this anywhere in my application and I believe nothing else is doing this either. As you've noticed I'm relatively new in this field and not quite sure what gets done by frameworks within this application. :)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `<%=request.getContextPath()%>`? Are you using `JSP`? You're okay, you got to start somewhere! :)

Comment: Also can you provide sample `JSON` data that you're trying to access with `url`.

Comment: Yes I am using jsp. Sure: 
{"total":3,"limit":15,"offset":0,"rows":[{
"quantity":1,
"manufacturingTargetDate":1528408800000,
"clerkPhone":null,
"glasOrderTargetDate":null}]}